# How to load a vue component in js file

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, components

I would obtain the following behavior: if in my database a certain condition is present, I would to load a specific vue.component instead of another. In other word, I have a file called `discover.js` that inside it has the following code:

```
Vue.component(
    'discover-component',
    require('./components/DiscoverComponent.vue').default
);
```

I would call the `DiscoverComponent.vue` only if the user (so in the db is set a specific boolean as true) and otherwise I would call another component. This is an example in pseudocode:

```
If flag is true:

    Vue.component(
        'discover-component',
        require('./components/TrueDiscoverComponent.vue').default
    );

Else:

    Vue.component(
        'discover-component',
        require('./components/FalseDiscoverComponent.vue').default
    );
```

Should I use AJAX call in this file .js to load the value of the `flag`? Is it legit? Or Is it a bad practice to call data inside a js file instead of a controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, I think you can use the async components. Something like this:

```
Vue.component('discover-component', async () => {
  const response = await fetch('/get-user'); 
  const user = await response.json();
  if (user.flag) {
    return import('./components/TrueDiscoverComponent.vue');
  }
  return import('./components/FalseDiscoverComponent.vue');
})
```

The link for async components documentation page: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-dynamic-async.html#Async-Components

Comment: Thank you too. Is it a good practice to do in a js file? I mean, to load data from db

Comment: If you have some logic related to that, then I think so

Comment: but if it's not a SPA then you can provide the flag from the controller and use the example without the AJAX call.

Answer (score 1):

I'd rather do it this way:

```js
import FalseDiscoverComponent from './components/FalseDiscoverComponent.vue'
import TrueDiscoverComponent from './components/TrueDiscoverComponent.vue'


Vue.component({
    'discover-component',

    components: {
        FalseDiscoverComponent, TrueDiscoverComponent 
    }

    template: `
        <div>
            <true-discover-component v-if="contidion" />
            <false-discover-component v-else />
        </div>
    `
})
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but the condition, so the variable that i need to load from db, should I pull it from an ajax request?

Comment: Yes you do, you can use `axios` for example

Comment: Isn't it an answer?